# How to make a panel mounted voltmeter/ammeter in my main panel up to code?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, code-compliance, nec, multimeter

I have already submitted a permit for and received approval to add a 50 amp inlet to my home for a portable generator. It will be 4-4-4-6 to an interlocked 50 amp breaker on my main panel. I'd like to monitor L1 and L2, I know it's not necessary but I would LIKE to and I'd also like to monitor the voltage of the utilities so I can see when the power has returned. I have seen the little inductive alarms but think this would look more clean. My question is, how do I make this up to code? I've added double fuses to possibly satisfy the inspector. I have also reached out to my county inspections department but wanted to see if anyone has done something similar or knew of some resources on this. I've been searching for a few days and I get blackholed by metering for billing purpose which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is the image of the 4-gang box a mock up of what you _want_ it to look like? Is it a real thing that you're going to install?

Comment: The 4 gang box is what I want it to look like and hopefully if I can convince the AHJ that it's up to code... I think what you're asking is if it's prefabricated? If that's your question then no, it's something that I'm going to make from a blank 4-gang wall plate.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what device you'll be using to monitor volts, amps, freq, etc, and what little display you'll be using?  It looks interesting.  The displays on the left, if they are intended to be realistic, will be illegibly small.  Wouldn't you rather buy something that will transmit all this data to a phone app rather than build a panel like this in your basement?   You k now, your next project will be a web cam pointing at this so you can see it from your phone. :)

Comment: Why not CTs on the utility just like on the generator?

Comment: Sure!
Generator Meters: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07YC1XHKQ/ref=crt_ewc_title_dp_6?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=AFHAE9RJVUMB

Utilities Meter: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01D891MHO/ref=crt_ewc_title_dp_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=AQ84B3B169D38

I think I might have to stack the generator ones but the point isn't remote monitoring just on startup and if I want to balance for running other loads like the water heater or heat pump. Just to control it at the panel.

Comment: @jay613 I was considering that too but I'd rather it tell me the voltage in case there's a brownout. I know I could just run it to a light to tell me if there was a presence of electricity back, but that's back to the inductive alarms basically.

Comment: That's cool, I like it.  If those things actually work (they are suspiciously cheap) this is a nice idea.  If the wires to your box are all in a conduit the only compliance issue you might have is that these devices are not UL-listed.  I don't know if that's a code issue.  You can build project devices and *plug them in* but IDK if you can wire them into a box like that.  Same goes for your little toggle switches, you may need to use proper light switches in another jbox for that, or just eliminate the switches.

Comment: Is there a permitted way to connect leads to the main lugs like that?  Why not just tap into a branch circuit on the safe side of a 15A breaker?  It should achieve the same thing.

Comment: @jay613 that's my problem, the bus bars will be energized by the generator due to the interlock so that meter for the utilities would just measure the generator as well since the main breaker would be off while the back-feed breaker is on.

Comment: Ah.  Well, this is out of my league but I do not think you can just connect extra things to your main panel lugs like that.  The proper way to do it will add so much to the project cost, it would not be worth it just to "know when power is back".   If you're going to splurge, you'd be better off turning your entire panel into a subpanel of a new main panel where you move some non-critical large loads and also take your tap.

Comment: @jay613 the toggles are Eaton's rated for 25 Amps at 250VAC. I understand what you're saying though and if the inspector wants that then that's what he'll get. My main thing is this won't be under any load. The voltage will be in the 220s for sure but the amperage will be so low and all the components are rated for way higher than both of the fuses on the setup.

Comment: IMO, when doing something home-made like this, the goal should be to do it as safe as possible rather than being code compliant.  I'm not sure if there is a way to make it "code compliant" because you're using components that aren't tested or listed for that purpose.  Best bet is to install the generator circuit with no monitoring devices and get that inspected, then add your monitors.

Comment: @JPhi1618 That's what I was worried about. I figured I was probably going to hit a wall because "it's not in NEC" or it's not listed.

Comment: @JPhi1618: you act as though "code compliant" and "safety" are separate, unrelated things. They aren't.

Comment: @whatsisname when dealing with things not covered by code, you have to understand the codes, what they are protecting against, and how to extend that to your project.  Code can't cover every thing anyone would ever want to do.

Comment: @jay613 A small connection to to mains can be done; code calls it a "tap." There are strict rules about it and I'm not well familiar with them, but IIRC tap conductors are limited to a distance about 25 feet and the wiring may have to be in conduit (?). Terminals must be rated appropriately; one can't simply assume it's OK to stick a 14 ga wire in the gap alongside the 4/0 main conductor for instance.

Comment: @GregHill yup you could use a tap *before* the main panel lugs.  I wonder if that can be housed inside the main panel?   OP appears to have ample space for it.  My guess that it would be expensive was on the basis you'd need another box just for the tap.  May be wrong.   And agreed, if the tap can be done properly, then routing through conduit and using approved overcurrent for the tap wires should be fine.  IDK if OP's fuses are approved.

Comment: @GregHill if we apply some common sense here, (which I wish the code took into account) these would be testing circuits hence load-less, and no need for 2-2-2-4 or greater. The concept is the same as placing test leads onto the lugs. Test lead wires are 18 gauge. Regardless, you'd just be avoiding the main issue, say I added a proper tap and service disconnect, in the other box would be the same issue, a small test lead wire connected to the meter and attached to the service wire. This seems like a dead-end issue and I'm just not going to do it.

Comment: But the White Book can.  @JPhi1618 what has taken you off the rails is *the underlying presumption that there MUST SURELY be a Code-legal path to do this kind of homebrewing*.  There is, but it ain't pretty: it requires getting the item *approved*, and in practice that means **by UL**.  For the specific purpose.  This is where other energy monitor attempts have gone wrong.

Comment: @Chris you are suffering confirmation bias because you want to do your project.  You are collecting (and rejecting!) information based on whether it helps you do this thing your way.  When you hear Code has issues with it, *you claim **Code** is unreasonable, you didn't ask what those issues are*. You have defaulted to the worst choice in every single product category from the wires to the junction box cover.  So here is my question.  Are you going to do this project your way anyway?  Or would knowing more about safety==Code actually make you do things differently?

Comment: I saw your edit and approved it. However, that means you've created a 2nd account because you should always be able to edit your own question w/o a review. Please see [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions on getting them merged.

Answer (score 1):

So many problems. For one, I see your backfeeding your generator into the panel. I hope you have an interlock kit for the main breaker.

Also,  you can't tap the service entrance wires like that and just put in a fuse block. What you are doing is tapping the service wires. Those wires you are adding are now service wires. The need to terminate at a service rated OCPD nearest the point of entrance. Also, the minimum size for service wires is #8 copper or #6 aluminum.

What you could do is tap the meter enclosure and bring in a separate service entrance with #8 copper and land it in a 30 amp fusible disconnect and then hook your voltmeter leads to the load side of that. Needs to be rated for services though and it must be located nearest the point of entrance. If you do this, you can shut off the 200 amp main and still safely monitor the grid voltage.

Comment: Useful tip: fusible pullout disconnects are service entrance rated *and* quite cheap

Comment: Yeah as long as it's rated you're good. Do it right or don't do it at all. 